# Does a TestFlight upgrade break Core Data schemes in an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, testflight

I've got an app that I'd like to send to beta testers using TestFlight.

We won't be changing the Core Data model, but I'm curious about two things:

1. When I send out an updated beta, is there any risk that the Core Data will be corrupted with the update?
2. When the app goes to the App Store, will our beta testers have to start fresh from the App Store version, or will their Core Data still appear in the App Store version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The user's data is stored in their own documents directory. If you haven't changed the scheme (or if you have and you have a proper migration set up) then just updating the app will not affect their own data - unless they delete and install the application again.
2. If you haven't changed the bundle identifier - and they don't delete and re-install their app - the data will still exist in the Document directory.

Comment: Abizem, do you know if the same is true for our beta testers / me when I upgrade to the version from the App Store?

Comment: @bryanjclark It works on the app bundle identifier. If you don't change that, then it won't change data when you update. But if you delete your application in the meantime - then it all goes away.

Comment: THANK YOU! Was really worried about that one! :)